# Nanotech - zero dimensional fullerene

Tags: atoms, spacetime-dimensions, nanoscience

Not really a physics junkie, and I think this is a chemistry question, but since there's no chemistry.stackexchange.com (yet) I think here is the best place.

I was just [reading up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene) on nanotech and came across the phrase "can construct 0D fullerenes, 1D graphenes...".    Flags went up at "0D fullerenes" and I can't find further information about it in many places.

A fullerene is apparently any pure-carbon atomic structure, in various forms, but the zero-dimensional part is throwing me.  What is a 0D fullerene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fullerene is a spherical structure (buckyball). They just mean that it does not have any dimensions in which it displays translational symmetry, in contrast to a sheet, lattice or tube.

Comment: Ahh, good answer!  I was trying to rephrase to make sure I understood, but my rephrasing led me to the same words as your answer.  +1 Cheers.